# Enter Parameter in microsoft access form always, even though script looks right

Tags: sql, ms-access

EDIT:  I guess I do not understand how the stuff for the subform is being used/retrieved based on the `frmInvoice` that is called.   The `frmInvoice` uses `tblInvoice` which is an archive table or one that doesn't get a record till the invoice is saved.  Yet the subform loads (before i started mucking with all this) with all the right information?
Sure enough editing the frmInvoice showed the Filter field to be that where clause.  So I guess I do not follow how the subform is getting the right groupID (in the original example) and presenting the right information from those queries based on this work flow.

I am trying to fix a database for someone, I am not too familiar with access vba.  So I am confused why the following isn't working.  I have a form, that when a button is clicked.  It opens another form with a subform.  The queries I changed a bit to include another field to key on.   So I have this script here:

```
Private Sub GroupAddress_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim intGroup As Integer
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    intGroup = Me![GroupID]
    strGroupName = Me![Group]
    stDocName = "frmInvoice"
    stLinkCriteria = "[GroupName]='" & strGroupName & "'"
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

End Sub
```

The line that sets the GroupName, Does not work, wants me to enter parameter GroupName.  But if I replace it with this line:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[GroupID]= " & intGroup
```

It works fine!  No question to ask

The subform record source is here:

```
SELECT qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.Provider, qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.GroupID, qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.Dues, qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.Adjustment, qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.AdjustmentDescription, qryInvoiceSubformSHANE.GroupName FROM qryInvoiceSubformSHANE;
```

The query that is from (qryInvoiceSubformSHANE) is here:

```
SELECT tblProvider!ProviderLName & ",  " & tblProvider!Designation & ",    " & tblProvider!ProviderFName AS Provider, tblProvider.GroupID, tblDesignation.Dues, tblProvider.Adjustment, tblProvider.AdjustmentDescription, tblProvider.GroupName
FROM tblGroup INNER JOIN (tblDesignation INNER JOIN tblProvider ON tblDesignation.DesignationID = tblProvider.DesignationID) ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblProvider.GroupID;
```

so not sure why this just doesn't work with the GroupName as the where clause?

Comment: Try this: -
 stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria  + "[GroupName]='" & strGroupName & "'"

Comment: edited my question.. it was confusing.

Comment: Can you please add the group name from database and also value from the code.

Comment: not sure what you mean?  the group name is 'Super Group LLC'   the value from code is there too... i put in a debugger.  that stLinkCriteria has it in there right.  Also if i set the qryInvoiceSubformSHANE to have the where clause GroupName = 'Super Group LLC' it works.?

Comment: Agree with @Sagar, include GroupID in the queries and apply filter to that field.

Comment: What table/query recordsource is *frmInvoice* bound to (not subform)?

Comment: You found it, it is going for that source (which is an archive table that holds the data).   Crud.   It seems I have to dig deeper for how this database was put together *bangs head on table*   Somehow the main form has all this archive data but then uses above queries to fetch new data from diff tables.